# XSLT / Xpath: How to remove a container layer

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given input like

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>everything below</c>
      <d></d>
   </b>
   <b>
      <c>everything below</c>
      <d></d>
   </b>
</a>
```

, is there a nice Xpath solution to get

```
<a>
   <c>everything below</c>
   <c>everything below</c>
</a>
```

, (so to say do an "unwrap-remove-select-wrap"), or how I would I achieve this most comfortably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, I think I could find what I want with your answers' help:

```
<xsl:for-each select="a">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="./b/c|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

... I think does what I wanted, without using additional templates, in a short and concise way.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Please explain. Mine is short, does not pollute namespace, and can be applied when context demands it (while templating might always break with unforeseen input. Not with regards to a given incomplete specification as in my OP, but with regards to actual real-world requirements which are most often a bit more context-sensitive than global templates obviously...)

Comment: @JoSo: Before making absolute statements, you need to know what you are talking about. Please, read about the identity rule and overriding it -- this is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. Your "solution isn't shorter -- you always need to have an `xsl:stylesheet` and an `xsl:template` instructions. The so called "solution" even isn't well-formed, because the namespace to which the `xsl:` prefix is bound, isn't defined. The downvote to this answer is fully deserved.

Comment: You still need to put this into a template body and copy-paste it whenever it is necessary, and because it is not a recursive solution it won't handle deeper than one level of unwrapping. If you need context-dependence that is not expressible by the `match` clause (in my experience this is very rare), you should use the `mode` attribute.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Thanks, I'll read up on that pattern. Though clearly, I was only looking for a fragment to fit into my existing stylesheet.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Deeper levels don't force you to do recursive templating, just use an Xpath like ".//b//c" (or "./b//c" or ".//b/c" or whaever is the requirement)--or what exactly did you mean that is not possible to do with Xpath?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="a | c">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<a>
  <c>everything below</c>
  <c>everything below</c>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//c"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's nice, but is there also a solution that does not force me into using another template?

Answer (score 0):

Try it out

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <a>
            <xsl:for-each select="//c">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following modification of the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) is probably the simplest and most elegant solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::b or self::d)]|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>everything below</c>
        <d></d>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>everything below</c>
        <d></d>
    </b>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <c>everything below</c>
   <c>everything below</c>
</a>
```

**Explanation:**

1. This modification of the identity rule copies every node "as-is" with the exception of any `b` or `d` elements.
2. Any `b` or `d` elements are processed by the default (builtin) XSLT template for elements, which applies templates on their children (they don't have such, so the desired "deletion" effect is achieved).